# Android Java query firebase null pointer exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a WHERE-clause-like query in Android using Firebase. Here is my code:

```
Database d = new Database();
mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
usersDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference(d.getUsersTable());
Query queryRef = usersDatabase.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
     }

     @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
});

// credential matches
if(user.getEmail().equals(email) && user.getPassword().equals(password)){
     Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
 }else{
     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid email or password. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

However, I am getting these error messages:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference 
at com.example.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:78)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19888)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check `user.getEmail()` or `user.getPassword()` is not null

Comment: Your `user` might be `null`

Comment: Yeah I tried to trace using the Log but nothing come out. I wonder is it the right way to perform the WHERE-clause-like query? Let me upload the database structure

Comment: I realized it does not even go into the onDataChanged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious your `user` object is null. To solve your problem, please use this code:

```
mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
usersDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String email = (String) dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue();
    String password = (String) dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue();

    if(userEmail.equals(email) && userPassword.equals(password)){
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid email or password. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which the `userId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` method.

`userEmail` and `userPassword` are the values with which you want to compare.

To get the `userId` from an activity to another, you can use an `intent` like this:

In your `FirstActivity` use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
startActivity(intent);
```

And to get the `userId` back in your `SecondActivity` use this:

```
String userId = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("userId");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry but where and how do I get the userID? It was randomly generated in my register class and I don't think I should parse it back to the Login class.

Comment: You get the `userId` in exact moment when you are using the `push()` method. `String userId = yourRef.getKey();` And than use it your `reference`

Comment: Sorry but does that mean I have to create a global variable userID?

Comment: No, the only thing you need to do, is to store the `userId` in variable, in the exact moment when you are using the `push()` method. After that, you'll be able to use that `userId` correctly in your `reference`.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused. I generated the push().getKey() and store as userID in Register class. But then I am calling the above method in Login class. Both of them are different classes, how am I supposed to know which userID in the Login class?